# Completely different results with Python 2.7 and Python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

So I am currently doing the google Foobar Challenge and as it turns out the newest one is in Python 2.7 and not in 3.8 anymore. I did not read up on this, shame on me, so I developed in 3.8 and have now encountered some anomalies which I am uncertain where they are coming from. I have already found out that there might be differences between the integer and the float division but I don't know if thats really the root of my problem. (I btw cant use from_future_)

On to the code:

```
import math
from math import gcd

def findmultiples(coordinates, list, dim):
    coords = coordinates[:]
    while (coordinates[0] <= dim[0] and coordinates[1] <= dim[1]) and (coordinates[0] >= -dim[0] and coordinates[1] >= -dim[1]):
        if tuple(coordinates) in list:
            list.remove(tuple(coordinates))

        coordinates[0] = coordinates[0] + coords[0]
        coordinates[1] = coordinates[1] + coords[1]
    return list


def solution(dim, your_position, trainer_position, distance):
    coordinate = [(x,y) for x in range(-dim[0] , dim[0]+1) for y in range(-dim[1] , dim[1]+1)]
    coordinate.sort()
    result = []
    for i in range(1):
        for x,y in coordinate:
            y_position = your_position[:]
            t_position = trainer_position[:]
            beam_position = your_position[:]
            distancetraveled = 0
            if x == 0 and y == 0:
                continue
            denom = gcd(x,y)
            x = x/denom
            y = y/denom
            while True:
                distancetraveled += math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y))
                if(distancetraveled > distance):
                    break
                beam_position[0] += x # add x coordinate
                beam_position[1] += y
                if (beam_position[0] > dim[0] or beam_position[0] <0 ): # Check if out of bounds along x-axis
                    t_position[0] = dim[0] - t_position[0] # Mirror the t_position along the y-axis
                    y_position[0] = dim[0] - y_position[0] # Mirror y_position along the y-axis
                    beam_position[0] = (beam_position[0] + dim[0]) % (2*dim[0])


                if (beam_position[1] > dim[1] or beam_position[1] <0 ): # Check if out of bonds along y-axis
                    t_position[1] = dim[1] - t_position[1] # Mirror the t_position along the x-axis
                    y_position[1] = dim[1] - y_position[1] # Mirror y_position along the x-axis
                    beam_position[1] = (beam_position[1] + dim[1]) % (2*dim[1])

                if (beam_position[0] == t_position[0] and beam_position[1] == t_position[1]):
                    coordinate = findmultiples([x,y], coordinate, dim)
                    count = 1
                    result.extend((x,0) for x in range(count))
                    break
                if(beam_position == y_position):
                    coordinate = findmultiples([x,y], coordinate, dim)
                    break

    return len(result)
```

It's rather short and the only difference I had to do (at least I thought so) to be able to run this on Python 2.7 was to change the second import to `from fractions import gcd` but apparently this does not work, as for some reason the program takes forever in line 10 `coordinates[0] = coordinates[0] + coords[0]`. I have so far not been able to finish the cProfile test I was running so I am currently assuming that the program is stuck there.
Now the differences I can observer (Because the program finishes) is with this `solution([3,2], [1,1], [2,1], 4)` the result comes back as 7 in Python 2.7(The correct result btw) and as 6 in 3.9. The second test with `solution([300,275], [150,150], [185,100], 500)` has of yet still not finished. I tried measuring timings with cProfile but the first test finishes too fast as for me to be able to see anything useful. (0.000s vs 0.001s)

I tried googling around and I was only able to find the difference and not too much more without diving into the 6.5k pages of Python 2.7.13 Documentation.

I hope someone can help me. Cheers

Edit: cProfile actually finished but without telling me a whole lot(Edit: It did actually tell me that findmultiples is called a whole lot more in this version, than it is in the other version:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    3.905    3.905 1417.093 1417.093 4.1.py:16(solution)
      689 1408.263    2.044 1412.459    2.050 4.1.py:5(findmultiples)
       26    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 4.1.py:51(<genexpr>)
        1    0.012    0.012 1417.105 1417.105 <string>:1(<module>)
   330463    0.208    0.000    0.208    0.000 fractions.py:18(gcd)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
  3638301    0.499    0.000    0.499    0.000 {math.sqrt}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
       13    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'extend' of 'list' objects}
      687    4.197    0.006    4.197    0.006 {method 'remove' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.015    0.015    0.015    0.015 {method 'sort' of 'list' objects}
      616    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 {range}
```

It took nearly 40 times as long as it did in Python 3.8.
1417s vs 37s with the main difference being that find multiples was called about 30 times more often. Which would explain the brunt of the difference.
I was able to find the problem(at least I think I did). For some reason the list.remove() as well as the gcd() functions worked a bit differently. I changed them to this:

```
index = list.index(tuple(coordinates))
list.pop(index)
list.insert(index, (0,0))
.
.
.
.
denom = gcd(x,y)
x = x/abs(denom)
y = y/abs(denom)
```

And now the code seems to be working the same in Python3.x and Python 2.x. Funnily enough in 2.x it is now about 20% faster but I can't be bothered to figure out why

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I have written? 
 'was to change the second import to "from fractions import gcd" but apparently this'

But I can change it so that it is a code snippet

Comment: sorry I missed the note you put in the body. I was expecting the code snippet to be python2

Comment: No worries. So the Answer to your initial question then is yes that is what I meant :)

Comment: "Over-a-decade-old, unsupported runtime is slower than modern version, news at 11". What's the actual problem here?

Comment: As for the results being _different_, my first suspicion is that that's a difference in how promotion between integers and floating point values is handled.

Comment: @Charles Duffy. Slower yes but python 2.7.13 was released in 2016 and is not supposed to be 40 times slower than python 3.9. That is just not the jump those two made
Tho I think the wrong result and the runtimes might be connected because it appears that findmultiples is called about 30 times more often in python 2.7. That is where most of the slowdown comes From. Might be that 'if in list' does not work properly.

Comment: There have indeed been some significant performance improvements in the Python3 series from just offering compiled backends to some standard library modules. For example, in Python2 you pull ``gcd`` from the *Python* module ``fractions`` but in Python3 from the *compiled* module ``math``. That ``findmultiples`` is called more often in Python2 suggests that some of your checks work differently with Python2's bias towards integer math, though.

Comment: "released in 2016", but with only security and correctness fixes from a release that came out in 2010 -- performance optimizations generally don't make it into point releases, where the idea is to be conservative.

Comment: Anyhow -- I'd suggest the title on the difference in the results, as opposed to the difference in runtimes, if that's what you really want investigated (and the runtime difference is secondary). Whereas if the runtime issue is the primary thing you're asking about, I'm not sure the question is on-topic at all (we're here for "practical, answerable" questions, and there are a lot of small improvements introduced throughout 3.x -- as well as some large ones, but there's unlikely to be One True Answer for the performance delta without other supporting factors as well)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was fixed with changing these pieces of code:

```
list.remove(tuple(coordinates))
.
.
.
.
denom = gcd(x,y)
x = x/denom
y = y/denom
```

To:

```
index = list.index(tuple(coordinates))
list.pop(index)
list.insert(index, (0,0))
.
.
.
.
denom = gcd(x,y)
x = x/abs(denom)
y = y/abs(denom)
```

I don't think the denom works any different in the different versions but the results are now exactly what I was expecting so I most likely had an error in my old code that resulted in the correct answers with the old list edit